# Css menu item / best way li and a or button

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

basically I've an item menu
which will have an icon + text with the menu open

and with closed menu only icon

I'm in doubt which best option I read + a
or button

I started trying for the button but I've problems:
I can't leave the text in the center of the icon

and not the icon in the center of the button

code:

```
<MenuDiv>
    <ButtonContainer>
      <Icon name='facebook' size='big' /> Facebook
    </ButtonContainer>
</MenuDiv>
```

styled comp:

```
export const MenuDiv = styled.div`
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: #d987;
   padding: 6px;
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
`;

export const ButtonContainer = styled(Button)`
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 50px;
   padding:0 !importante;
   color: white !important;
   text-align: left !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
   background-color: red !important;
`;
```

I want this:

[image]

I got this:

[image]

example on codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-goldstine-gps3s

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't leave the text in the center of the icon

and not the icon in the center of the button`? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: basically the text is above the icon a bit

it doesn't seem centralized

Comment: I believe it is because my icon is not centered I tried it all the way and couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to fix your `text-align: left !important;` to
  `text-align: center !important;` or try to put `margin: auto` for the "Facebook", change this:

```
text-align: left !important;
```

to this:

```
`text-align: center !important`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is here in this sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-sea-hekws

the following are the changes:

- Added style in index.html: you have to import `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" />` this is to show the icons.
- ButtonContainer style: I changed the `background-color:blue` and added some padding : `padding: 5px 10px !important;`
- Icon: `<Icon name="dashboard" size="big" /> Dashboard`

Comment: I believe that this will test thank you very much bro

Comment: Hello I switched to facebook icon and realized that the icon still goes on as if it had not center aligned and the text too

Comment: so you want to center the text in the middle? I will check the sandbox and fix.

Comment: Não falo no centro do botão

em largura
mas sim em altura

Comment: basically it seems to me that the icon is not in the center of the button
I think the problem is the icon and not the text

Comment: I fixed it, check again I change this `text-align: left !important;` to `text-align: center !important;` https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-sea-hekws